# how an object can obtain a pointer to the class object it belongs to c++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

Penelope object will need to access the getKey() method in the GameWorld class (which is the base class for your StudentWorld class), Penelope object (or more likely, one of its base classes)
will need a way to obtain a pointer to the StudentWorld object it belongs to. If you look at code example, you’ll see how Penelope’s doSomething() method first gets a pointer to its world via a call to
getWorld() (a method in one of its base classes that returns a pointer to a StudentWorld), and then uses this
pointer to call the getKey() method.

```
void Penelope::doSomething()
{
    int ch;
    if (getWorld()->getKey(ch))
   {
    // user hit a key during this tick!
      switch (ch)
   {
       case KEY_PRESS_LEFT:
         ... move Penelope to the left ...;
         break;
      case KEY_PRESS_RIGHT:
        ... move Penelope to the right ...;
        break;
      case KEY_PRESS_SPACE:
         ... add flames in front of Penelope...;
         break;
   // etc…
  }
}
...
}
```

code for getWorld() is actually required

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parent object by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248191/passing-parent-object-by-reference)

Comment: If you need to get the pointer (or a reference) to some other object frequently, then pass it along to the constructor and save it in the object.

Comment: If you need code for that `getWorld` method, why not write it? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i cant understand how it wil work

Comment: Nico Haase please help me to write this function if you can

Comment: Joe mallone it is not Parent-child thing

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude help me in how an object pass its own reference through a function

Comment: Is `GameWorld` calling `doSomething` on a `Penelope` object it has access to?

Comment: @Caleth yes there is an object or pointer I created in studentWorld class which is inherited from Gameworld

Comment: Can you change `doSomething` to take a `GameWorld *` as a parameter? and then you would change the call from something like `penelope.doSomething();` to `penelope.doSomething(this);`

Comment: @Caleth no But any other new function can be created

Comment: What's the source of all these restrictions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal example compatible with your question

```
#include <iostream>

class GameWorld {
  public:
    int getKey(int & k) const { k = 123; }
};

class StudentWorld : public GameWorld {
};


class Student {
  public:
    Student(StudentWorld * w) : world_(w) {}

    StudentWorld * getWorld() const { return world_; }

  private:
    StudentWorld * world_;
};

class Penelope : public Student {
  public:
    Penelope(StudentWorld * w) : Student(w) {}
    void doSomething();
};

void Penelope::doSomething()
{
  int ch;

  getWorld()->getKey(ch);
  std::cout << ch << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  StudentWorld sw;
  Penelope pe(&sw);

  pe.doSomething();
}
```

I give/memorize the world through a pointer rather than a reference/weak_ptr because strangely *getWorld* visibly returns a pointer

I do a direct inheritance between Penelope and the owner of *getWorld()* even the question says it may not be direct, and I name that owner *Student* just because seem consistent

In the question *Penelope object* is strange and must be *Penelope's object* or *Penelope instance* because *Penelope* is a class rather than an instance

---

New version because of your remark where the *Penelope* instance is created by *StudentWorld* but you have to understand like that *StudentWorld* knows *Penelope* class and this bad, a fabric or something like that have to be used. May be *StudentWorld* known *Student* to memorize all of their instances but certainly not a child class like *Penelope*

```
#include <iostream>

class GameWorld {
  public:
    int getKey(int & k) const { k = 123; }
};

class Penelope;

class StudentWorld : public GameWorld {
  public:
    Penelope * createPenelope();
};


class Student {
  public:
    Student(StudentWorld * w) : world_(w) {}

    StudentWorld * getWorld() const { return world_; } 

  private:
    StudentWorld * world_;
};

class Penelope : public Student {
  public:
    Penelope(StudentWorld * w) : Student(w) {}
    void doSomething();
};

Penelope * StudentWorld::createPenelope()
{
  // probably the instance is not just returned
  // but also memorized to save all the students
  return new Penelope(this);
}

void Penelope::doSomething()
{
  int ch;

  getWorld()->getKey(ch);
  std::cout << ch << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  StudentWorld sw;
  Penelope * pe = sw.createPenelope();

  pe->doSomething();
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -g w.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
123
```

Comment: actually, I don't have access to the main function. I have to create Penelope object or pointer to StudentWorld class and also call something() there too

Comment: @zamanchaudhary whatever the _main_, I just did it to have a full working program. But you have to understand there are thousand ways to do to be compatible with your question

Comment: look you create StudentWorld object first in main then pass it to Penelope constructor but the problem is I crated Penelope within a function of StudentWord class now how can I pass its reference to Penelope

Comment: @zamanchaudhary I edited my answer, but it seems your problems are deep :-(

Comment: at this line
getWorld()->getKey(ch);

these errors came
Error C2027 use of undefined type 'StudentWorld'

Comment: @zamanchaudhary because you put on several files, visibly an #include is missing in your source. Sorry but all of that is basis of C++

Comment: and what does this mean
 E0393 pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed ZombieDash

Comment: @zamanchaudhary the same thing, an #include is missing, the name is known as a type but just that,  **incomplete class type** is a clear message . Did you just search on internet ?